# Result of sosl query convert to list and show in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, sosl

```
public List<sObject> sobjlst {get; set;}
public void find() {
    if(searchText != null && searchText.length() > 1){
        List<List<SObject>> results = [FIND :('*' + searchText + '*') IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
            Contact (Id, Name, Email, Account.Name,MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, MailingState, MailingCountry,Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s) ,
            Account (Id, Name, Billingstreet, Billingcity, BillingPostalcode, Billingstate, Billingcountry, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s) ,
            Lead (Id, Name, Email, street,city,postalcode,state,country, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s)
            ];
        contacts = (List<Contact>)results[0];
        acc=(List<account>)results[1];
        lea=(List<lead>)results[2];
         if(results!=null && results.isempty()){
         for(list<sObject> objectList :results ){
            sobjlst .addall(objectList);
           }
           }
        if(sobjlst.isEmpty()){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'No matches for "' + searchText + '"'));
        } else {
            serverSideGeocode();
        }
    } else {
        if(sobjlst != null) {
            contacts.clear();
        }
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please provide at least 2 characters for the search.'));
    }
}
```

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!find}' in component  in
>   page findnearby1: Class.mapController.find: line 31, column 1
>
> Class.mapController.find: line 31, column 1

Vf page :

```
<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:pageBlock id="searchBlock">
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!find}"/>
        <p>Examples: <a href="/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}?q=USA">"USA"</a>, "Singapore", "Uni", "(336) 222-7000". If it works in the global search box, it will work here.</p>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Found {!sobjlst.size} Contact(s)..." rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(sobjlst)) && sobjlst.size > 0}" id="resultsBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton value="Clear cached locations" title="Click if you want to set 'null' as geolocation info for all these contacts" action="{!clearGeocodedData}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sobjlst}" var="c" id="contacts">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.label}">
                <apex:outputLink value="../{!c['Id']}">{!c['Name']}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <pre id="log"></pre>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

How can I correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

2 things to consider:

1. The for loop is wrong here. sobjlst is a list of sObject and you are adding list. The code will break here.

`for(list<sObject> objectList :results ){sobjlst.addall(objectList);}`

2. `if(sobjlst.isEmpty())` this check is resulting into NullPointerException. Since sobjlst is not initialized or assigned any value, its null and you can't use .(dot) operator in a null variable.

As a solution, initialize your sobjlst like this before the for loop.

```
sobjlst = new List<sObject>();
```